# Android Facebook 3.0 SDK, Request Dialog, install, access to data attribute

Tags: android, facebook, dialog, request

The Request Dialog in Facebook's 3.0 SDK creates a very nice experience for sending an invitation from one user, in-app, to another user that may or may not already have the same app installed.

The documentation clearly describes how to pass additional data through with that request. It looks like it is very easy to read this data in the scenario where the recipient already has the app installed.

What I would like to know is whether there is some way to read the data if the recipient must first install the app? My instinct says no, and that the user would have to click the notification again to launch the app post-install. But perhaps there is some Facebook magic sauce to obtain this data? Does anyone know?

I want this data in order to give the sender credit for an install. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I would like to know is whether there is some way to read the data if the recipient must first install the app?

No, there is indeed not, because you need the combination of the request id and the user id to read the `data` value – and you do not get the user id if the user has not connected to your app yet.